# What it is the best way to release UIViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently building a little sample iOS app, i developed my UIViewControllers and views programatically, i'm targeting iOS 7+ devices and i have a simple question :
Here how i show a new controller

```
 MySuperController *superController = [[MySuperController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController showViewController:superController sender:self.navigationController];
```

First i wanted to know if it's the correct way to show another view controller ? 
Second imagine i'm performing those instructions in a LoginViewController that will be displayed just once (typically when the user launches the app) how can i release this loginviewcontroller after creating and showing another view controller ? 
i know this question has been already asked but all the solutions presented are old/inappropriate (my sample app is ARC enabled which is by default enabled i think)

I'm new to this environnement any help/indication is appreciated thank you

Comment: If you're using ARC then you don't need to release viewcotroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roy Nakum says in his comment, if you are using ARC, your code is fine. You create your view controller using a local strong variable, then present it. At that point the navigation controller takes ownership of it. Since your strong reference is a local variable, it does not keep ownership after your method returns.

However there is another problem with your code. This line will likely cause you problems:

```
MySuperController *superController = [[MySuperController alloc] init];
```

You should not use `init` to create a view controller. It won't have any contents. You should either use `initWithNibName:bundle:` (to load a view controller from a NIB) or `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` (to load a view controller from a storyboard.)

It is **possible** to set up a view controller so its "plain" init method loads it's views, but it takes special handling in the init method, and it's not the normal way to do things.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thank you very much for your answer, nice remark, since u asked me i'll told you why i did this and tell me if its good or not if you want :) actually i'm using init because i don't have storyboards or NIB so in my MySuperController i'm overriding viewdidload with view creation, i have custom views (HomeView, LoginView...etc) those views are created and set as root view inside the viewdidload method of the appropriate custom UIViewController, is this nasty?

Comment: Using `init` is fine when you create views in code. The correct method to override is `loadView` not `viewDidLoad`. Your implementation of `loadView` should not call `[super loadView]`.

Comment: @FruityGeek beat me to the punch, and the info in his comment is correct in every particular. You should be overriding `loadView`, not `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: However, I advise against creating views in code. It is a lot more work up front, is much, much harder to maintain, and it prevents your from using a lot of facilities that are built into the IDE and frameworks. It's kind of like trying to write your program in assembler. You can do it, but why?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good way to present a ViewController. If you have ARC enable (default) don't worry about releasing, it will release automatically.

Comment: Thank u @Dante one more question the dealloc method is never called, is it normal ? does it mean that ARC waits until memory usage go up before starting to delete unused objects ? or does ARC have some sort of cleaning cycle ?